# gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

This error has arise when I add gns repository and try to use this command:

```
#sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F88F6D313016330404F710FC9A2FD067A2E3EF7B
```

the error is:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

Comment: as I've explained in my answer and comment to the downvotes, it's related to DNS and the way that dirmngr in version 2.1.6 did reverse DNS that have been removed in version 2.1.8 I recall, but 2.2.x I've installed from Debian testing/unstable (Debian 9 current as at writing this) also fixed this issue.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Behind a firewall you should use the port 80 instead of the default port  11371 :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9A2FD067A2E3EF7B
```

Sample output:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.mTGQWBR2AG/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9A2FD067A2E3EF7B
gpg: key 9A2FD067A2E3EF7B: "Launchpad PPA for GNS3" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Comment: Not port 11371 or 80 related behind firewall. seems to be rather related to DNS resolution when you start to google the net...
```
   Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.imkAGGXMO8/gpg.1.sh --receive-keys --debug-all -vvv --keyserver hkp://sks1.cryptokeys.org.za:80 gpg:    DBG: chan_3 -> KEYSERVER --clear hkp://sks1.cryptokeys.org.za:80
   gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_3 -> KS_GET -- 0x9C1384B1168FD423
gpg: DBG: chan_3 <- ERR 167772379 Server indicated a failure <Dirmngr>```

Comment: I get the same error using dirmngr 2.2.5, and adding `hkp://` and `:80` resolved the issue

Comment: Thanks. FInally I solved the issue by following command - `sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`

Comment: works like a charm!

Answer (score 23):

This issue was really tough for me; none of the proposed solutions worked for me until I found this [post on reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/6v5xlg/gpg_server_indicated_a_failure/)
I just went and added this line to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Google DNS
```

you can try any other DNS and see which one works for you, such as

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1 # Cloudflare
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unless the first nameserver in the list is functional. Most DNS activity will failover to the next resolver, but this wouldn't for some reason.

Comment: nameserver 1.1.1.1 is a better option

Answer (score 14):

This problem can be caused (as I just experienced it) by an empty `resolv.conf`, as may be the case on a system using `systemd-resolved` for its primary DNS resolution via `nsswitch`.

I assume that it's a case of `gpg` not using `nsswitch` and the associated libc functions and instead, for some reason, reading `resolv.conf` itself.

### Symptoms:

- `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure`
- `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty but hostname resolution e.g. `getent hosts google.com`, `ping google.com` etc is fine. Note that `dig`, `drill`, `nslookup` all read `resolv.conf` directly, so these may not work.
- `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has something like `hosts: files mymachines myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns` in it, where `resolve` is a module provided by systemd (see `man 8 libnss_resolve.so.2` for details).

### Resolution:

You want to make a symbolic link to systemd's autogenerated `resolv.conf` that reflects the current resolver settings. I suggest reading `man 8 systemd-resolved`, section "/ETC/RESOLV.CONF" for details on what this does, exactly. Here are my recommended commands and output to make the symbolic link:

```bash
$ # you should check this has reasonable contents before using it
$ cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad

$ rm /etc/resolv.conf
$ ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. `ll /etc/resolv.conf` shows that this was _already a symbolic link_ to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`! Here is the output of `ll /etc/resolv.conf`: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug  9  2020 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. And yet, it still didn't work. So, I changed the nameserver from `nameserver 127.0.0.53` to `nameserver 1.1.1.1`, as recommended [by this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510464/114401), and now it works! Note that if you don't have `ll`, it is simply an alias for `ls -alF`, so use that instead.

Answer (score 9):

It has to do with DNS and what your DNS server does or does return for dirmngr ;(
It got introduce since 2.1.16 with dirmngr, and I've been looking for solution myself on 2.1.6 with Debian's default packages. ;(

The *correct* answer, is: Upgrade to version 2.2.x or later that fixed this problem first time.

Comment: a temporary workaround: ping the server (`ping keyserver.ubuntu.com`) to get its IP number and use this number instead of keyserver.ubuntu.com in your command

Comment: Relevant bugfix in 2.2+ https://dev.gnupg.org/T3374

Comment: @XavrasWyzryn Thank you, this comment helped me identify a server that is no longer operational, which is why I was getting the error.

Answer (score 6):

Encountered the same issue on ubuntu 18.04, running dirmngr 2.2.4. I went with the option of checking my dns settings and added my local dns server 'nameserver 1.1.1.1' and google's 'nameserver 8.8.8.8'. Then it worked.

Comment: Specifying explicit DNS servers in my network config solved it for me.  Gentoo, using NetworkManager.

Comment: Also remember Quad9 (9.9.9.9) for helping to filter out malware/etc. in a privacy-advocacy manner ;)

Comment: Where add??? I just switched to dns 1.1.1.1 and am getting this issue

Answer (score 4):

Add `0x` before key, so that it turns `0xF88F6D313016330404F710FC9A2FD067A2E3EF7B`.

This plus GAD3R's answer solved it for me.

Comment: damn, you're right! i would have never imagined that the missing 0x will not only make it fail, but also lead to such a cryptic message... thanks!

Comment: I think you'll find that the `0x` is purely a placebo fix.

Answer (score 3):

This also works to remove the DNS issue:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver $( dig +short keyserver.ubuntu.com | head -n1 ) \
                 --recv-keys 42670A7FE4D0441C8E4632349E4FDC074A4EF02D
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you have a non default DNS configuration in your system, for example if you're using `dnsmasq` or another DNS service, other than `systemd-resolve`, it's possible that `dirmngr` used by `gpg` fails to get the resolved name for keyserver.ubuntu.com, then, you need to check your name resolution software.

In my case, I have installed `dnsmasq` for name resolution in a Zimbra mail server. In this case it is important that you prevent that the `resolvconf` software controls `dnsmasq`, this is editing the `/etc/default/dnsmasq` file and uncommenting this line: `IGNORE_RESOLVCONF=yes`. Then you have to restart the `dnsmasq` and try to resolve with the local dns server with this command:

```
:~$ host -v keyserver.ubuntu.com 127.0.0.1
```

If it is ok, you will see something like this:

```
Trying "keyserver.ubuntu.com"
Using domain server:
Name: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
Aliases: 

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 13994
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;keyserver.ubuntu.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
keyserver.ubuntu.com.   417 IN  A   162.213.33.8
keyserver.ubuntu.com.   417 IN  A   162.213.33.9

Received 70 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 14 ms
Trying "keyserver.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33907
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;keyserver.ubuntu.com.      IN  AAAA

Received 38 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 1 ms
Trying "keyserver.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45211
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;keyserver.ubuntu.com.      IN  MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.     1748    IN  SOA ns1.canonical.com. hostmaster.canonical.com. 2018053167 10800 3600 604800 3600

Received 99 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 16 ms
```

Even if you're not using some DNS server, try to ask to `systemd-resolve` if it can resolve the URL with this:

```
:~$ host -v keyserver.ubuntu.com 127.0.0.53
```

If not, let us know what you get.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error on when I tried to access a key.

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

Killing dirmngr and running the command again solved it for me, like below:

```
gpgconf --kill dirmngr
```

It is worth a try, let me know if it works.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me on Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 1):

If you are living in **Belarus**, than you need to know that `gpg` issue may be cased by new buggy state **firewall**. Today state firewall in Belarus may block `hkps` using `DPI` for you. It is actually a bug: you can report it directly to [firewall managers](https://belgie.by/ru/home) if you think this organization will change something.

If you want your `hkps` (and `hkp` too) back, than you have to follow complete china users firewall experience:

1. remote [openvpn](https://openvpn.net/) server in [normal country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO).
2. [obfs4proxy](https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4) server (not required for now).
3. [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/) server.
4. frontend domain ([azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/)) (not required for now).
5. stunnel client.
6. obfs4proxy client (not required for now).
7. openvpn client.

See also [gentoo issue](https://bugs.gentoo.org/716370).

Comment: I am in Russia, and we have the same issue nowadays. (We are lagging behind by a few months only in the thickness of our firewall.) -- I had to bypass getting the keys by using the #apt-get --allow-unauthenticated, as in my answer below. All the best in surviving...

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my 2 days of troubleshooting:
Symptoms:

- gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
- /etc/resolv.conf is using stub 127.0.0.53 but resolves hostname fine  (ie. getent hosts google.com work as expected)
- more than 1 ethernet adapter that is up

Troubleshoot:

- open another terminal and execute `journalctl -u systemd-resolved -f`
- in the first terminal do `systemctl edit systemd-resolved`

paste

```
 [Service]
 Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

restart

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolve<br/> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
F88F6D313016330404F710FC9A2FD067A2E3EF7B
```

check in the auxiliary terminal, the adapter it is using and the fail
to be sure that this the cause, just set down the ethernet adapter and repeat the key request if, it works now, you may understand that the adapter do not have a satisfactory name server;

**adding 8.8.8.8 to the netplan config of the 1st adapter will solve the problem**

Answer (score 0):

I live in a totalitarian country* with thick firewall, and neither adding :80 nor editing resov.conf helped

I was forced to use #apt-get --allow-unauthenticated to bypass getting the keys...

*Russia