# How to set resolv.conf to use the DNS supplied by the default gateway?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

For some reason - I have no idea why - my `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search home
```

This is a problem, because I have a local nameserver, serving local domains. Currently, my laptop resolves domains on the internet just fine, but local domains are not resolved.

Now, whenever I read about `/etc/resolv.conf`, it says everywhere that you should enter whatever name server you want to use here. So if I want to use 8.8.8.8, this is what I enter into resolv.conf. Obviously, in that case, I would want to enter the local IP address of my local DNS server.

Except that then my laptop wouldn't be able to resolve anything when I take it with me to work. So I need a way to enter into resolv.conf: "use whatever nameserver the default gateway recommends", and I can't find that anywhere. Anyone?

Comment: If you read https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/612416/5132 you will gain an idea why.

Comment: Are you using **NetworkManager**? If so, you can use it to configure your DNS servers.